# JLabels move with border change

Tags: java, netbeans, icons, border, jlabel

Basically I want to hover over a jLabel and change its border to Bevel (raised) so as to appear clickable. The problem is when I hover over it the border changes but it moves all my other jlabels, as soon as I remove the mouse pointer from it they move back to where they were. Been driving me nuts can't seem to figure this out. 
 The only way I've found to stop this from happening is using absolute layout, problem is when I resize my window it eats some of the jLabels. Also tried putting that panel with absolute layout inside another panel which has another layout like box or border layout.
  This happens with any of my jLabels, what am I missing?

Comment: Add a transparent border to all your labels, then the rest of your labels won't shift because it wont be adding a border only changing its appearance.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a million @thermite :)